# How to create case-insensitive text search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a search function that works perfectly for my application except that I can’t figure out how to make it case-insensitive. Here is an example of some HTML:

```
 <div id='search_count'>
   <div id='count'><?php  get_count('notes', 'tasks') ?>
   </div>
    <input type="text" id='search_notes' placeholder='Search'/>
   </div>

   <div class='task'>
    301 closet  
   </div>

 <div class='notes'>
 <p>The old manager opened a panel that needs to be closed.</p>
 </div>

 <div class='task'>vacuum halls </div>

 <div class='notes'><p>The halls need to be vacuumed every week!</p></div>
```

This JavaScript will filter the divs with class=’notes’ just like I want, but only case-sensitive. How can I do this case-insensitive?

```
$("#search_notes").keyup(function () {
    var search_notes = $(this).val();
    $('.task, .notes').css('display', 'none');

    $("div.notes:contains(" + search_notes + ")")
        .css('display', 'block')
        .prev().css('display', 'block');


    var count = $('div.notes').filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
    }).length;

    $('#count').text(count);
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse and search through HTML? ... I hope this isn't intended for real-world use.

Comment: Convert the text you're searching with and the text you're filtering through to the same case. (this can be done on side variables to preserve the already shown HTML). I like .toLowerCase() but pick your poison of coice (upper v lower)

Answer (score 2):

You have to test both lowercased values against each other using [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method:

```
var search_notes = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$('.task, .notes').css('display', 'none');

$('div.notes').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === search_notes;
}).forEach(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('display', 'block')
    .prev()
    .css('display', 'block');
});


var count = $('div.notes').filter(function() {
return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
}).length;

$('#count').text(count);
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting this error in the console-TypeError: $(...).filter(...).forEach is not a function